# How to formulate a smart ranking system that stops in either top 3, 5 or 10?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formulated a ranking system in Excel that stops when it meets a certain condition. It is all based on if conditions. Here are the lists of important conditions:

The grades must be greater than or equal to 75 to qualify in the rankings.

If there are similar grades (2 or more) their ranks should be the same. For example, the grades are (99, 98, 98, 97), their ranks should be (1, 2, 2, 3) respectively.

If the ranking system went past top 3 and cannot complete top 5, it should stop in top 3 only. Same applies to top 5 but cannot complete top 10. For example, the grades are (98, 97, 97, 83, 78, 74, 74) their ranks should be (1, 2, 2, 3, [BLANK], [BLANK], [BLANK]) because the ranking system should only compute top 3, 5, or 10 only. 78 is still qualified in the rankings but there are no more grades below it that qualifies so the ranking stops at top 3 only.

Here is my formula:

=IF(OR(N2<75, P1=""), "", IF(P1=3, IF(N2=N1, P1, IF(N3>75, P1+1, "")), IF(P1=5, IF(N2=N1, P1, IF(N6>75, P1+1, "")), IF(P1=10, IF(N2=N1, P1, ""), IF(N2=N1, P1, P1+1)))))

This is placed in the second row (P2) and it will only work if there is a value above it (P1). The problem with my formula is that if there are several similar grades (3 or more), it will continue its ranking.

I was hoping for an alternative ranking formula or if it's possible to do, or if its possible to apply to all columns including the first (P1).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get started. Assuming your data is in a single column, unsorted (say column A):
Add a sorting column next to it:

```
=FILTER( SORT(A:A , , -1) , A:A<>"")
```

You can adjust the range of cells, but the filter will take out empty cells.

Or you could already sort out values below the threshold:

=FILTER( SORT(A:A , , -1) , (A:A<>"")*(A:A>=75))

Next up you can asign them ranking numbers with RANK.EQ in a next column:

```
=IFERROR(RANK.EQ(B1:Bx,B:B) , "")  'Where x is the last cell in that column
```

**Edit: they can be nested, so here's what that looks like:**

```
=RANK.EQ( FILTER( SORT(A:A, ,-1) , A:A>=75) , A:A)
```

NOTE that this ranking system isn't exactly as you asked for, duplicates will get the same number, but they skip previous numbers:

(93,90,78,78,75) will turn out as (1, 2, 3, 3, 5)

Now this isn't the full solution yet, I haven't figured out yet how to make it stop at 3, 5 or 10; but my best guess you could make it with a IF statement and a XMATCH, I'll try and figure one out later today (if you haven't gotten another/more finishing answer).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that ranking formula too. Unfortunately, I also can't figure out how to stop it at 3,5 or 10 so I made my own which is also not quite great when there are same grades. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would use some extra columns for intermediate calculations. I'll assume that the grades are listed in column N, starting in row 2, and we can use columns P, Q, R, and S for (intermediate) results.

- In `P2` put: `=IF(N2>=75, IF(ROW() = 2, 1, OFFSET(P2,-1,0)+(N2< OFFSET(N2,-1,0))), "")` and copy the formula downwards.
- In `Q2` put: `=MIN(10, MAX(P:P))`
- In `R2` put: `=IF(Q2<5,MIN(Q2,3),IF(Q2<10,5,Q2))`
- In `S2` put: `=IF(P2>R$2,"",P2)` and copy the formula downwards.

Here is what could be the result (depending on the grades):

[image]

Then hide the columns P, Q and R, since they have intermediate results only.